# Sumifs() function in excel second condition is not working?

Tags: excel-2016

I want to be able to use `sumifs()` for two conditions. If the section is groceries and the month is September, I want it to sum it. If I take away the second condition, it sums the 286.55, but if I leave the second condition in `sumifs()` then it gives me 0.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one of two issues...

**1** You are trying to match a date with a string. To check I would do a `=B2*1` & `=I2*1`. If both of them give error then you are ok.
**2** The strings are different(one of them  has a trailing space etc.) Try `=LEN(B2)` & `LEN(I2)`. I'm sure one of them is `>9`.

You would know what to do by yourself